# When do you get a VIP card?

Tags: support, user-card

Regarding the VIP name card (which expands if you hover over it)

I see that some users with a gazillion reputation have a normal name card, and some with less than 1000 have a VIP hover card. Based on which rule do you get a VIP name card for stackexchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get it at a 1000 points, but you must have at least 28 characters in your "About Me" section:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user